# reportlab, find position/coordinates for last paragraph in page

Tags: python, reportlab, pdfrw

I need to insert some text after last paragraph on last page, am not sure if it is possible to find coordinates for last paragraph.

As I know reportlab is most robust library for dealing with pdf, however if that is possible via another library will be fine.

Also to ask is it possible to replicate (find font attributes like name and size for last paragraph)?

What I have

```
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from pdfrw import PdfReader
from pdfrw.toreportlab import makerl
from pdfrw.buildxobj import pagexobj

input_file = 'abc.pdf'
output_file = 'def.pdf'

# Get pages
reader = PdfReader(input_file)
pages = [pagexobj(p) for p in reader.pages]
canvas = Canvas(output_file)
lastpage = pages[-1]

for page_num, page in enumerate(pages, start=1):
    canvas.setPageSize((page.BBox[2], page.BBox[3]))
    canvas.doForm(makerl(canvas, page))

    if page == lastpage:
        canvas.saveState()

        # helpful code might come here

        canvas.restoreState()

    canvas.showPage()

canvas.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution is in Great pdfminer python library from Yusuke Shinyama. 5 stars for his project.

pdfminer is at present available only for python2.7

Is installing from source after unpacking archive with

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

After instalation commandline tool pdf2txt.py can be used like

```
/usr/local/bin/pdf2txt.py -t xml file.pdf > xmlfile.xml
```

with all needed information and more then that!